# Camera access in qr code scanner dont have access on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, qr-code

I use this qr code scanner: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

In chrome everything works fine, but in firefox I have allert: AbortError: Starting videoinput failed.

My code:

```
function listcamera() {
    Html5Qrcode.getCameras().then(cameras => {
        if (cameras && cameras.length) {
            cameraId = cameras[cameras.length - 1].id;
            scan(cameraId);
        }
        
    }).catch(err => {
            // handle err 
                alert(err);
    });
}

function scan(cameraId) {
const html5Qr = new Html5Qrcode("reader");
html5Qr.start(
   cameraId, // retreived in the previous step.
   {
      fps: 10,    // sets the framerate to 10 frame per second 
      qrbox: 250  // sets only 250 X 250 region of viewfinder to
                  // scannable, rest shaded.
 },
 qrCodeMessage => {     // do something when code is read. For example:
     console.log(`QR Code detected: ${qrCodeMessage}`);
   [...]
                });
                //console.log(data);
           
       
//        $( "#erase" ).click(function() {
//   document.getElementById('text').value = '';
// });
 },
 errorMessage => {     // parse error, ideally ignore it. For example:
     console.log(`QR Code no longer in front of camera.`);
 })
 .catch(err => {     // Start failed, handle it. For example, 
     console.log(`Unable to start scanning, error: ${err}`);
 });
};
listcamera();
```

Thanks for help with this issue in firefox.

Comment: It requires an HTTPS connection unless you are working in the `localhost`. What does the `console` say?

Comment: I use https, console say nothing

Comment: (Code author here) Can you retry with the latest version of the code on https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode